# Why is my RenderTransform only occuring once?

Tags: c#, wpf, translation, transformation

I have a rectangle and on my `MouseMove` event I want to transform the rectangle whenever the rectangle's width has changed.

I have code sorta like this:

```
private Rectangle _rectangle;

public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    _rectangle = GetTemplatedChild("PART_RangeRectangle") as Rectangle;
    if(_rectangle != null)
    {
        _rectangle.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(_rectangle_MouseMove);
    }
}

private void _rectangle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && _rectangle != null)
    { 
        _rectangle.Width += 50;
        _rectangle.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-10, 0);
    }
}
```

My Xaml looks sorta like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Name="PART_RangeRectangle" StrokeThickness="5"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" />
    <Canvas>
</Grid>
```

When I first trigger the `MouseMove` event the translation occurs as expected.  But this only occurs once. I am getting into that block of code and the width of the rectangle is updating fine, but I've yet to figure out why the transform is not updating.

Comment: for giggles I did try replacing a RenderTransform with a LayoutTransform but nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried calling the UpdateLayout..? by chance

Comment: yes I have and with no luck :(

Comment: here is a Link that may help you look at this and see if it sheds some light.. http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html

Comment: I'm creating a custom control and in the template for the control I have this rectangle. I use GetTemplatedChild("PART_RangeRectangle") to gain access to it from code. That's what _rectangle is. I'll update the code to show my OnApplyTemplate method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the old transform with an identical transform. You need to modify the existing transform and use += like you do with Width.

Example:

```
if (_rectangle.RenderTransform is TranslateTransform)
{
    (_rectangle.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform).X -= 10;
}
else _rectangle.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(-10, 0);
```

Comment: can you provide an example of that?

Comment: Ahhhhh...I see. Doh! I'm so used to dealing with transforms in xaml @_@ I made this more difficult that it had to be. I knew it was something simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing your transform. Assigning a RenderTransform does not move the rectangle, it sets an offset. You're not changing that offset after your first assignment.